# Adding User to Multiple Security Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been able to add a user to one group using the below code.

```
Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1480"' | %{Add-ADGroupMember "HS Students" $_.SamAccountName}
```

I want to add the user to multiple groups though. HS and HS Students.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

so adding to the bottom of my create user script gives me the messages that the user is already part of the groups I'm trying to add to. Any reason why that is happening.

```
   foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
   {
   #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a  variable as below

$Username   = $User.ID
$Password   = $User.BDATE
$Firstname  = $User.FNAME
$Lastname   = $User.LNAME
$Department = $User.GRD
$Company    = $User.SCHID #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be moved to

# Choose OU
Switch ($Company)
{
    "1480" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=hs,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
    "1479" {$OU = 'OU=students,OU=users,ou=elem,dc=clasd,dc=net'}
}

#Check to see if the user already exists in AD
if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
{
     #If user does exist, give a warning
     Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
}
else
{
    #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
    "Processing started (on " + $date + "): " | Out-File $log -append
    "--------------------------------------------" | Out-File $log -append

    #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
    New-ADUser `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -UserPrincipalName "$Username@clasd.net" `
        -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
        -GivenName $Firstname `
        -Department "$Department" `
        -Company "$Company" `
        -EmailAddress "$Username@clasd.net" `
        -Surname $Lastname `
        -Enabled $True `
        -Scriptpath "login.vbs" `
        -DisplayName "$Firstname $Lastname" `
        -Path $OU `
        -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
        -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

    #Start-Sleep 5

    # Add User to Groups
    Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1480"' | % { Add-ADGroupMember "HS Students" $_.SamAccountName; Add-ADGroupMember "HS" $_.SamAccountName }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need to add a `;` after the first command.

```
Get-Aduser -filter 'company -eq "1480"' | % 
{ Add-ADGroupMember "HS Students" $_.SamAccountName; Add-ADGroupMember "HS" $_.SamAccountName }
```

You could use that as a 1 liner, if you really want, its just looking nicer the way I formatted it.

Comment: Thanks. That works as it should. Any reason why it would tell me the users are already added to the group when I  add it to my create user script. See my edit.

Comment: in that case you should mark it as an answer ;) as for your second question, I'm not sure why it does that, judging by your code it shouldn't, perhaps you should create another question for that